# How has += operator been implemented in c++?

Tags: c++, operators, default

This is a question I've always pondered on and have never found any resource stating the answer to this question. In fact its not only for `+=`, but also for its siblings i.e. `-=`, `*=`, `/=`, etc. (of course not `==`).

Consider the example,

```
int a = 5;
a += 4;
//this will make 'a' 9
```

Now consider the equivalent expression:

```
a = a + 4;
//This also makes 'a' 9
```

If `+=` were simply a shorthand for `a = a + <rhs of +=>`
overloading + operator should also implicitly overload `+=`, unless explicitly overloaded otherwise. But that isn't what happens. That means, `a += b` doesn't get converted to `a = a + b`. But then why wasn't it implemented this way? As in, wouldn't it have been easier to simply convert it to `a = a + b` during compilation instead of implementing it separately as an operator in itself? That would also help in operator overloading, where `a += b`, where `a` and `b` are objects of the same class would not have to be explicitly overloaded, and simply overloading `+` would have been enough?

---

EDIT:
My question becomes more clear with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64130441/11930602) answer
Let me explain my question with an example where one needs to overload the operators:

```
class A {
    int ivar;
public:
    A() = default;
    A(int par_ivar) : ivar(par_ivar) { }
    A(A& a) {
        this.ivar = a.ivar;
    }
    A(A&& a) noexcept {
        this.ivar = a.ivar;
    }
    A operator+(const A& a) const {
        A temp_a;
        temp_a.ivar = this.ivar + a.ivar;
        return temp_a;
    }
    void operator=(const A& a) {
        this.ivar = a.ivar;
    }
    ~A() = default;
};
```

Now, let's take a look at the result of 2 programs:
prog1:

```
int main() {
    A a1(2);
    A a2(3);
    a1 = a1 + a2;  //a1.ivar = 5
    return 0;
}
```

prog2:

```
int main() {
    A a1(2);
    A a2(3);
    a1 += a2;  //compilation error!!
    return 0;
}
```

Even when both the programs meant to do, nay, do the same thing, one compiles and runs (hoping that my overloads are correct) the other does not even compile!! Had += been simply replaced by appropriate + and =, we would not have felt the need for an explicit overload of +=. Was this intended to be, or is this a feature waiting to be added?

Comment: *"Now considering that += is simply a shorthand"* - Not quite. `a` is only evaluated once in `a += b`, whereas `a = a + b` will have `a` evaluated twice. That's a major difference if `a` involves a function call.

Comment: Operators are not generated from others (except with/from `<=>` in C++20): providing `operator <` doesn't allow `a > b` (which is indeed "logically" equivalent to `b < a`). You have to implement all (even by re-using some).

Comment: there's no "background". For class types `+=` and `+` are different operators

Comment: When I overload my own `+` and `+=` operators for a class, I implement the `+` in terms of `+=`, not the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operators are not generated from others (except with/from <=> in C++20):

providing `operator <` doesn't allow `a > b` (which is indeed "logically" equivalent to `b < a`). You have to implement all (even by re-using some).

For classes, `a += b` is not a shorthand for `a = a + b`

but for `a.operator +=(b)` or `operator +=(a, b)`

In the same way `a = a + b` is a shorthand for `a.operator=(operator +(a, b))` (or its variant)

In practice, it is more efficient to implement `operator+` from `operator +=` than the reverse.

Even if a user might expect similar behavior according to their names, they are regular functions.

I already saw a matrix iterator for which `++it` increase column index whereas `it++` increase row index.

> If `+=` were simply a shorthand for `a = a + <rhs of +=>` overloading + operator should also implicitly `overload +=`, unless explicitly overloaded otherwise. But that isn't what happens. That means, `a += b` doesn't get converted to `a = a + b`.

(Possible) rational to not generate might be performance and control:

Vector (for math) or Matrix are good example:

4 possible overloads

```
Matrix operator+(Matrix&& lhs, Matrix&& rhs)      { return std::move(lhs += rhs); }
Matrix operator+(Matrix&& lhs, const Matrix& rhs) { return std::move(lhs += rhs); }
Matrix operator+(const Matrix& lhs, Matrix&& rhs) { return std::move(rhs += lhs); } // + is symmetrical :)
Matrix operator+(const Matrix& lhs, const Matrix& rhs) { auto tmp{lhs}; return tmp += rhs; }
```

Side effect of the decision allow to give different meanings to operators, as "name operator":

```
if (42 <in> std::vector{4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42})
```

Comment: For built-in type, discussion is mostly non relevant, it is compiler which provides those operator.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 • the built-in `+` and `+=` are independent of each other, and both trace their lineage back to C from which C++ inherited.  50 years ago with a non-optimizing compiler, a `+=` could compile to a different single opcode from the two opcodes for `+` and `=`, so was a micro-optimization.  These days with VERY POWERFUL compiler optimizers, the performance aspect is a non-issue and `+=` could be considered redundant.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 • I'd prefer Jarod42 update his excellent answer with the extra bit of information (if he so choses).  Implementing your own compiler, since a primitive type will only be read once and written once, then yes `+=` could easily be implemented in terms of `=` and `+` (and then the optimizer on the back-end could change them back to the optimized `+=` equivalent if appropriate for the given CPU).  That wouldn't be applicable for user types and user defined overloads, of course.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31: You can create your own language :) For built-in, `a += b;` and `a = a + b;` provide same result. for custom class, they not necessary does the same thing.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31: *"Was this intended to be, or is this a feature waiting to be added?"* yes and possibly.

Comment: *I already saw a matrix iterator for which `++it` increase column index whereas `it++` increase row index.*  well, that's an evil non-iterator.

Answer (score 2):

Using `a = a + b` will imply using a [copy assignment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment) (as `operator =` is used). On the other hand, `a += b` is by default a compound assignment.

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment),

> copy assignment operator replaces the contents of the object a with a copy of the contents of b (b is not modified).

and

> compound assignment operators replace the contents of the object a with the result of a binary operation between the previous value of a and the value of b.

Using `a = a + b`, would therefore cause an unnecessary memory usage, since `a` has to be copied once before its value is changed.

Comment: I think, correct me if I'm wrong, that [fundamental types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) (such as `int` or `float`) will be treated as any other class, as long as default operator implementation is concerned.