# What are the breaking changes caused by rewritten comparison operators?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, comparison-operators

There are some new rules about rewritten comparison operators in C++20, and I'm trying to understand how they work. I've run into the following [program](https://godbolt.org/z/sPWzTs):

```
struct B {};

struct A
{
    bool operator==(B const&);  // #1
};

bool operator==(B const&, A const&);  // #2

int main()
{
  B{} == A{};  // C++17: calls #2
               // C++20: calls #1
}
```

which actually breaks existing code. I'm a little surprised by this; `#2` actually still looks better to me :p

So how do these new rules change the meaning of existing code?

Comment: Which compiler? Do other compilers do the same thing? What happens if you remove either definition for both language versions?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm gcc and clang have consistent behavior as far as I can tell. Removing `#1` calls `#2` in both versions, and removing `#2` fails to compile in c++17, neither of which are breaking changes. And both those results are expected I think.

Comment: This seems to come about because of stuff in `[over.match.oper]` (section 12.4.1.2 Operators in Expressions in N4849). In particular the paragraphs talking about _rewritten candidates_ are all new, and there's wordage in there that seems to allow using `y==x` (reversing the operands). I'm not sure how much of that should be included in an answer.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm You're right, I don't actually want the specific rules per se, I can work through that. It's more I don't understand *why* `#1` is a better choice. I'm not sure how to rephrase the question though.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Ok, edited the question a bit. Now only the rules needed to explain why the behavior of the program has changed, need to be in the answer.

Comment: Do either of the compilers warn about this change? I can understand that you might have different operator== for various forms of const-ness, but not combined with change between member and non-member and different order of arguments.

Comment: @HansOlsson No warnings at all, unfortunately.

Comment: Why would the compiler warn? The process it follows for overload resolution seems to be well laid out in the standard, whether or not developers fully understand it yet (don't take that the wrong way, I'm not sure even *I* understand it fully yet). Putting aside the rewriting aspect, it also doesn't warn about `void fn(const int &x) { std::cout << x << " A\n"; } void fn(int &x) { std::cout << x << " B\n"; } int main() { fn(7); int a = 8; fn(a); }` either, even with `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`, flags that normally complain if you even *look* at them suspiciously :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo I'ts not that there is no warning per se, it's that there is no warning for a breaking change. It's nice to not have to worry about changes in behavior just by upgrading the version.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not *necessarily* convinced this is a *breaking* change, unless the `A::operator==` and `operator==(B const&, A const&)` somehow did different things, which I would consider already broken :-) While this is possible, it seems unlikely. Yes, it's a *change* but I consider a breaking change to be one where that has an effect on the outcome. Still, I understand your POV.

Answer (score 35):

That particular aspect is a simple form of rewriting, reversing the operands. The primary operators `==` and `<=>` can be reversed, the secondaries `!=`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, and `>=`, can be rewritten in terms of the primaries.

The reversing aspect can be illustrated with a relatively simple example.

If you don't have a specific `B::operator==(A)` to handle `b == a`, you can use the reverse to do it instead: `A::operator==(B)`. This makes sense because equality is a bi-directional relationship: `(a == b) => (b == a)`.

Rewriting for secondary operators, on the other hand, involves using *different* operators. Consider `a > b`. If you cannot locate a function to do that directly, such as `A::operator>(B)`, the language will go looking for things like `A::operator<=>(B)` then simply calculating the result from that.

That's a simplistic view of the process but it's one that most of my students seem to understand. If you want more details, it's covered in the `[over.match.oper]` section of C++20, part of overload resolution (`@` is a placeholder for the operator):

> For the relational and equality operators, the rewritten candidates include all member, non-member, and built-in candidates for the operator `<=>` for which the rewritten expression `(x <=> y) @ 0` is well-formed using that `operator<=>`.
>
> For the relational, equality, and three-way comparison operators, the rewritten candidates also include a synthesized candidate, with the order of the two parameters reversed, for each member, non-member, and built-in candidate for the
> operator `<=>` for which the rewritten expression `0 @ (y <=> x)` is well-formed using that `operator<=>`.

---

Hence gone are the days of having to provide a real `operator==` and `operator<`, then boiler-plating:

```
operator!=      as      !  operator==
operator>       as      ! (operator== || operator<)
operator<=      as         operator== || operator<
operator>=      as      !  operator<
```

Don't complain if I've gotten one or more of those wrong, that just illustrates my point on how much better C++20 is, since you now only have to provide a minimal set (most likely just `operator<=>` plus whatever else you want for efficiency) and let the compiler look after it :-)

---

The question as to why one is being selected over the other can be discerned with this code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct B {};
struct A {
    bool operator==(B const&) { std::cout << "1\n"; return true; }
};
bool operator==(B const&, A const&) { std::cout << "2\n"; return true; }

int main() {
  auto b = B{}; auto a = A{};

           b ==          a;  // outputs: 1
  (const B)b ==          a;  //          1
           b == (const A)a;  //          2
  (const B)b == (const A)a;  //          2
}
```

The output of that indicates that it's the `const`-ness of `a` deciding which is the better candidate.

As an aside, you may want to have a look at [this article](https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2019/07/28/comparisons-cpp20/#rewriting-secondary-operators), which offers a more in-depth look.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the question then is *why* is the synthesized candidate (`#1`) a better match?

Comment: The arguments are not const. The member is non-const, so it wins.

Comment: @T.C. Aah, I think that's it. To clarify, the rewritten operator mimics the const-qualifiers of the original operator?

Comment: RE: *Hence gone are the days of having to provide a real operator== and operator<, then boiler-plating*: This is what I was essentially asking for when I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61575287/how-has-operator-been-implemented-in-c) question, implementing one operator in terms of the remaining!... or am I again wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with C++. What's the <=> operator?

Comment: @Nzall https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-way_comparison

Answer (score 23):

From a non-language-lawyer sense, it works like this. C++20 requires that `operator==` compute whether the two objects are equal. The concept of equality is commutative: if A == B, then B == A. As such, if there are two `operator==` functions that could be called by C++20's argument reversal rules, then your code should behave *identically* either way.

Basically, what C++20 is saying is that if it matters which one gets called, you're defining "equality" incorrectly.

---

So let's get into the details. And by "the details", I mean the most horrifying chapter of the standard: function overload resolution.

[[over.match.oper]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.match.oper#3) defines the mechanism by which the candidate function set for an operator overload is built. C++20 adds to this by introducing ["rewritten candidates"](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.match.oper#3.4): a set of candidate functions discovered by rewriting the expression in a way that C++20 deems to be logically equivalent. This only applies to the relational and in/equality operators.

The set is built in accord with the following:

> - For the relational ([expr.rel]) operators, the rewritten candidates include all non-rewritten candidates for the expression x <=> y.
> - For the relational ([expr.rel]) and three-way comparison ([expr.spaceship]) operators, the rewritten candidates also include a synthesized candidate, with the order of the two parameters reversed, for each non-rewritten candidate for the expression y <=> x.
> - For the != operator ([expr.eq]), the rewritten candidates include all non-rewritten candidates for the expression x == y.
> - For the equality operators, the rewritten candidates also include a synthesized candidate, with the order of the two parameters reversed, for each non-rewritten candidate for the expression y == x.
> - For all other operators, the rewritten candidate set is empty.

Note the particular concept of a "synthesized candidate". This is standard-speak for "reversing the arguments".

The rest of the section details what it means if one of the rewritten candidates gets chosen (aka: how to synthesize the call). To find which candidate gets chosen, we must delve into the most horrifying part of the most horrifying chapter of the C++ standard:

[Best viable function matching](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.match.best#2).

What matters here is this statement:

> a viable function `F1` is defined to be a better function than another viable function `F2` if for all arguments i, ICSi(F1) is not a worse conversion sequence than ICSi(F2), and then

And that matters... because of `this`. Literally.

By the rules of [[over.ics.scs]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.ics.scs), an identity conversion is a better match than a conversion that adds a qualifier.

`A{}` is a prvalue, and... it's not `const`. Neither is the `this` parameter to the member function. So it's an identity conversion, which is a better conversion sequence than one that goes to the `const A&` of the non-member function.

Yes, there is a rule further down that explicitly makes rewritten functions in the candidate list less viable. But it doesn't matter, because the rewritten call is a better match on function arguments *alone*.

If you use explicit variables and declare one like this `A const a{};`, then [[over.match.best]/2.8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.match.best#2.8) gets involved and de-prioritizes the rewritten version. [As seen here.](https://godbolt.org/z/1TjeTM) Similarly, if you make the member function `const`, you also [get consistent behavior](https://godbolt.org/z/8T8bva).

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Is it specifically stated anywhere that the rewritten operator has the same const-qualification as the original operator? Or does that not matter?

Comment: @cigien: I'm not sure what you mean. The effects of `A{} == B{}` with regard to `const` qualfiication are well specified. So when the standard says to find candidates based on the expression `y == x`, there's nothing more that needs to be said.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding this; the compiler sees `A::operator==(B const&)` and synthesizes something like `B::operator==(A const&)`. Is that right? If so, could the compiler synthesize `B::operator==(A const&) const` which is more natural for this operator anyway?

Comment: @cigien: The compiler does not synthesize functions. It synthesizes *expressions*, which then resolve to an overload set of functions that are considered during overload resolution. Just look at the text I quoted from the standard about exactly how it works.

Comment: `bool A::operator==(const B&) const` [is selected](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b21fef963c8ab4a)

Comment: Any suggestions for equalities that are intentionally non-commutative, or otherwise violate the assumptions that C++20 introduces?

Comment: @TLW: Then don't use `==` for those things. Commutative behavior from `==` is hardly an unreasonable thing for a user to expect.

Comment: "Commutative behavior from == is hardly an unreasonable thing for a user to expect." This logic is worrisome. C++ had - past tense being key - prioritized backwards compatibility. Is this change in attitude expected, going forward?

Comment: @TLW: "*C++ had - past tense being key - prioritized backwards compatibility.*" They still do. But they don't let compatibility be the only thing that matters. If you look at the appendices in the standard, you'll find plenty of edge cases for compatibility breaks. C++11 had lots of them, beyond just a bunch of new keywords. For example, C++98/03 allowed any constant expression of the value 0 to be a null-pointer constant; C++11 said that only an integer literal 0 can be a null-pointer constant. But that's a much better rule, and it only breaks code that was rather weird.

Comment: @TLW: The same goes for expecting equality to be commutative. The code was already broken; the standard just made it more official. In fact, I suspect more code was broken when C++11 added its narrowing rules for list initialization than this rule expecting commutative equality testing.

Comment: @NicolBolas - please do not conflate 'niche' with 'broken'.

Comment: @TLW: Don't conflate "someone used it" with "this is a good idea that should be supported."