# undefined behaviour and C++ language stability

Tags: c++

I was [told](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63898114/is-there-a-way-to-do-not-change-the-export-in-main/63898224#comment112992747_63898224) that `#defining` language keywords is undefined behaviour.  How does this play with the following facts:

1. Users can `#define` names that are not keywords in their code.
2. The language can get new keywords that used not to be keywords over time.
3. Users should be able to compile old code with new compilers and get a compile-time diagnostic rather than undefined behaviour if any construct they used has ceased to be supported.

#3 is obviously my assumption but I consider this assumption essential as newer compilers tend to be better and "knowing the whole extent of the current law" is a theoretical legal assumption that does not apply to software developers, I hope (if the compiler assumed otherwise, it could replace any compile-time error in the code with whatever undefined behaviour it pleases).

Comment: The question you link to has been deleted so it does not help. Many of us can not see it.

Comment: @drescherjm, users with more than 10k can see it.

Comment: @anastaciu: Not everyone has more than 10k rep. So again, not helpful.

Comment: I actually knew that but it will still be awhile before I get to that level..

Comment: @NicolBolas, yes, I was just pointing that out.

Comment: The comment that you linked to doesn't say anything more than you have in your question. Just remove it.

Comment: You don't need to go as far as this UB case: a new, colliding keyword would typically cause a syntax error. That's mainly why C++'s new keywords are a tad far-fetched (`constexpr`, `consteval`, `co_await`, someday `reflexpr`...)

Comment: @drescherjm For the record: the question was asking how can someone use `export` as a name for member function (they were given `main()` function which they were supposed to not change). OP here posted an answer that suggested doing `#define export really_export`

Comment: @drescherjm, nonsense, you're almost there ;)

Comment: TBH, I wonder why 3. doesn't hold true already. It should be quite simple feature for compilers to report a warning if `#define <keyword>` is encountered.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: #3 does not hold true *generally*, not just for adding new keywords. There have been [several features added](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64130311/734069) in various version that silently change the meaning of code. It's not super-common, but it does happen. Nobody ever said that it wouldn't, so you shouldn't expect it to not happen.

Answer (score 8):

#3 is not the case and has never been guaranteed by anyone. While the C++ committee does not like to create backwards incompatibilities that don't noisily break, they still sometimes do it.

You shouldn't expect a thing that you were not told to expect.

And yes, it's possible that adding a new keyword breaks silently for those who `#define`d that keyword. This is one of the many reasons why users are told to use ALL_CAPS for their `#define` names, since keywords will almost certainly not be in ALL_CAPS.

Comment: Surely the compiler could recognize when you're using `#define` with a keyword, so the question is why doesn't the standard require a diagnostic for that condition?

Comment: @MarkRansom: That's not the question the OP actually asked.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Quoting Raymond Chen, "because that feature starts at -100 points". Since there's already a recommendation to shy away from macro's, and since there's an additional recommendation to use upper case if you do need a macro, the benefit of that diagnostic simply does not outweigh the default position of _not_ having the diagnostic. Additionally, from the perspective of standardising practice, existing implementations don't do that, and users aren't asking for it.

Comment: @MarkRansom: It's about an expectation that the OP expects but shouldn't, because it's not guaranteed by anyone. Which is the point of my answer.

Comment: And the point of my comment is that there's no good reason the standard shouldn't require it, despite the point made by @MSalters.

Comment: @MarkRansom: And I'm saying "that's not the point". Even if the standard did require that, it wouldn't resolve #3 ***generally***; the [committee could still make changes that alter the behavior of existing code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64130311/734069).

Answer (score 1):

C++ standards are not fully backwards-compatible. That doesn't hold you back from using a modern compiler.

If you want to compile old code with a new compiler, you set the C++ version explicitely with a flag. For example, with GCC, the default C++ version varies with version. To set it explicitely, you use the `-std` option, e.g. `std=c++11` or `std=c++0x`.

Then any keywords introduced after this version will not be in effect so you will not run into undefined behavior. If you would like to use the newer language features on the other hand, you need to go through the documented newly introduced keywords and some subtleties that changed and review your code accordingly.

Comment: perhaps: once you stay with one standard, any changes on the stnadard are irrelevant and you are not quite answering the question

Comment: @idclev463035818 I don't get it. A standard is obviously not changed but a new version of the standard is written when adding keywords.

Comment: the question is about code written and compiled against standard X and what happens when you compile the same code with X+1. You just say "stay with X". (not my vote btw)

Comment: Yes, I just say that C++ standards are not fully backwards compatible. That's a known fact, and the answer to the question. Yes I know it's not your vote and appreciate your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

> #3 Users should be able to compile old code with new compilers and get a compile-time diagnostic rather than undefined behaviour if any construct they used has ceased to be supported.

This is a good thing to strive for, but there is technically no such guarantee.

> #2 The language can get new keywords that used not to be keywords over time.

Yes. Because of desire to keep existing programs working, the standards committee is usually against introducing new keywords, but it does happen regardless.

For those cases where a new keyword is introduced, there is a trick to avoid name collisions (with high probability) with your macros: Use upper case. None of the C++ keywords with the exception of `_Pragma` use upper case, and this is likely to stay true in future. For other identifiers than macros, using keywords makes the program ill-formed, so you are guaranteed a diagnostic.